# How to normalize amplitude differeces within the 433Mhz signal burst in GNU Radio Companion?

Tags: gnuradio-companion, rtl-sdr

I'm learning **SDR** by trying to decode different **433Mhz** keyfob signals.

My initial flow for capture and pre-processing looks like this:

[image: Flow]

What I get on the sink is:

[image]

I guess the bits are visible fine and I could proceed to decode it somehow. But I am worried about the big difference in the amplitude: the very beginning of the burst has much higher amplitude in comparison to the rest of the packet. This picture is very consistent (I was not able to get bursts with more balanced amplitudes). If I was speaking about music recording I would look for a ***compression*** method. But I don't know what the equivalent in the SDR world is.

I'm not sure if this will be a problem when I'll try to quadrature demod, binary slice and/or clock recover.

Is this a known problem and what is the approach to eliminate it within **GNU Radio Companion**?